# Scripting Google Apps Presentation

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to script combining several presentations (google format) into one.  I don't see a specific `Presentation` service along with `Documents` and `Spreadsheet`.  Is there a way to do this within the `Documents` service?

Answer (score 0):

There's currently not a service in Apps Script for manipulating Google Presentations. You can request this via the [Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).